# How to clear "remember my choice" flag on MIUI 12

Tags: adb, xiaomi, usb-debugging

I wanted to use VSCode and the flutter extension to debug an app on my phone. While starting the debugger my phone asked if I wanted my PC to allow installing Apps. I pressed remember my choice and then accidently clicked deny. How can I clear this remember my choice flag. I tried by clicking Revoke USB debugging authorizations in the developer settings and then reauthorize again but that didn't work. I also tried disabling the USB debugging and enable it again, also didn't work.

I'm using a Xiaomi Mi 10 Ultra with MUI 12

Answer (score 1):

I just found the setting.
In the settings searchbar look for Install via USB (Security) and the there should be a list of denied Apps which you can then allow.